# How to use the attention layer in tensorflow 2.0 with the sequential model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model

I haven't found much information about this, but I'm thinking there must be a way since there exists a

```
tf.keras.layers.Attention
```

What would be the correct way of connecting this layer to an existing seq2seq Sequential tensorflow model?

this is currently about what I have

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=training_x[0].shape, dropout=0.5))
model.add(RepeatVector(daysToPredict))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, dropout=0.5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='linear')))
```

Is there a way to add the Attention layer somewhere in here?

Comment: This layer could not be used with Sequential API since at least it depends on two input tensors (unless you have a single layer which generates both of that two tensors). You need to use Functional API.

Comment: Around where would I put the attention layer in the functional api model? It would take in the state of the encoding lstm and be placed right before the TimeDistributed(Dense)) layer?

Comment: I am not sure what your application is. It could be implemented as various ways. For example, for self attention you can pass the same tensor as `query` and `value` arguments, and this tensor in your model could be the output of LSTM layer. Or you could pass the output of two LSTM layers (assuming both return all the hidden states). See [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Attention) and the example there to get more ideas.

Comment: The documentation gives 2 inputs for the attention layer. I think for my case, it would be that the attention takes in the encoders output, however would that mean that I need the return_sequences=True option for the encoder? If that were the case, how can I pass that output to the RepeatVector layer? Also, if this made sense, would I need to use a Concatenate layer somewhere to combine the attention and the decoder outputs? hope the 2 questions made sense

Comment: What 2 values should I pass into the attention layer? I'm not certain what the 2 arguments (query, value) mean in this context.